# Como incrementar uma variavel string c#

Tags: c#

Tenho estado a desenvolver uma nova aplicação de facto preciso de incrementar a variavel

```
public string malcoins = "0";
```

bom para começar nao poderei por o codigo todo pois e muito grande e aqui so aceita ate um certo numero de caracteres eu ja tentei antes sem sucesso.
bom aqui nesta parte do codigo que eu preciso de incrementar a variavel e depois fazer o refresh da variavel que supostamente e um tipo de pontuacao dada ao usuario ou retirada 
aqui a varialvel e posta em uma label

```
label2.Text = malcoins;
```

e aqui quando o usuario clica no butao

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(messageTextBox.SelectedText);
        Process.Start(Clipboard.GetText());

        malcoins = Convert.ToInt32(malcoins) + 100;
        deletemenssage();

    }
```

eu tentei assim com o codigo assima mas sem sucesso de eleminar o erro.
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'
TestForm.cs 961 24

Comment: A variável malcoins  foi declarada como string, você ta tentando atribuir um inteiro no clique do botão.

Comment: Malcoins precisa realmente ser uma string ?

Comment: nao de facto  nao pode ser um int mas eu nao sei como por o valor int depois em label.text = malcoins e da me sempre esse erro

Comment: Se for executar cálculos onde os resultados são sempre números inteiros é interessante que malcoins seja do tipo int e não string. Para atribuir em label.Text é só utilizar malcoin.ToString();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Opção 1

Fazer do jeito certo e alterar o tipo da variável `malcoins`

```
public int malcoins = 0;
```

No evento de clique

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Clipboard.SetText(messageTextBox.SelectedText);
    Process.Start(Clipboard.GetText());

    malcoins = malcoins + 100;
    deletemenssage();
}
```

E alterar na hora de mostrar no `label`

```
label2.Text = malcoins.ToString();
```

#### Opção 2

Converter o resultado do cálculo para `string` para colocar na variável `malcoins`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Clipboard.SetText(messageTextBox.SelectedText);
    Process.Start(Clipboard.GetText());

    malcoins = (Convert.ToInt32(malcoins) + 100).ToString();
    deletemenssage();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Resolveu o problem 5 estrelas